# How do terms cancel out when changing independent variable bases?

Tags: thermodynamics

Take for example the equilibrium constant which is a function of the temperature yet the Gibbs:
$$\Delta G=-nFE=-RTln\frac{K}{Q}=\sum \mu \Delta N +V \Delta P+S\Delta T$$
how does Q(concentration), K(temperature) get separated into the sum of independent variables N P and T?
Typically when addition is made into multiplication we have a ln but the pressure and number of moles seems to disappear becoming functions of concentration and temperature

Comment: You seem to be equating infinitesimal and finite quantities here, so these equations cannot be correct. Are you possibly confusing the value of $G$ with the infinitesimal change its value $dG$

Comment: @Symmetry i have fixed the issue

Comment: Many undefined variables. What is $n$, $F$ and $E$? What do you mean by $Q(\text{concentration})$ and $K(\text{temperature})$?